# Letters transforming

Tags: javascript, css

guys! I have some code with rtl transformation, but letters in here have wrong transformation (rotation). Don't know how to explain it completely. It's hard to read. I hope you'll understand. Could someone help to me?

```js
function wrap(element) {
  var text = element.getAttribute('data-original');
  if (!text) {
    text = element.textContent.trim();
    element.setAttribute('data-original', text);
  }

  var words = text.split(/\s+/);
  var result = '',
    line = '',
    reverseLine = false;
  element.innerHTML = 'a';
  var height = element.offsetHeight;

  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    var candidate = line + ' ' + words[i];
    element.innerHTML = result + candidate;
    if (element.offsetHeight > height) {
      height = element.offsetHeight;
      result += '<div>' + line + '</div>';
      line = words[i];
    } else {
      line = candidate;
    }
  }
  if (line) result += '<div>' + line + '</div>';
  element.innerHTML = result;
}

function wrapAll() {
  console.time('wrapAll()');
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.text-inverse'), wrap);
  console.timeEnd('wrapAll()');
}
wrapAll();
window.onresize = wrapAll;
```

```css
.text-inverse div:nth-child(2n) {
  direction: rtl;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="courses">
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <time class="date" datetime="2016-11-08"></time>
  <p class="course text-inverse">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at cursus nisi. Morbi in quam eget quam aliquet laoreet vitae ac metus. Suspendisse nulla risus, faucibus vel lacus ac, sagittis accumsan nunc. Ut eleifend elit vitae commodo posuere. Donectincidunt, nulla vel ullamcorper tempor, nisl libero pretium tellus, eget luctus sem tellus in mi. Curabitur hendrerit urna in facilisis posuere. Ut ornare quis nibh et tincidunt. Mauris id orci a nisi lacinia eleifend sed id lectus.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to read the odd lines from right to left and the words from left to right.

So you need to get each odd line and reverse the order of the words.

If you have the string of the odd line:

1. Split on whitespace and generate array
2. Reverse the the chars of the words
3. Concat the reversed order as string

Attention: You should also check, if there is a dot in the end of the word and put it on the start (so it will appear on the "end").

```js
function wrap(element) {
  var text = element.getAttribute('data-original');
  if (!text) {
    text = element.textContent.trim();
    element.setAttribute('data-original', text);
  }

  var words = text.split(/\s+/);
  var result = '',
    line = '',
    reverseLine = false;
  element.innerHTML = 'a';
  var height = element.offsetHeight;

  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    var word = words[i];
    var candidate = line + ' ' + word;
    element.innerHTML = result + candidate;
    if (element.offsetHeight > height) {
      height = element.offsetHeight;
      result += '<div>' + line + '</div>';
      line = word;
    } else {
      line = candidate;
    }
  }
  if (line) result += '<div>' + line + '</div>';
  element.innerHTML = result;
}

function wrapAll() {
  console.time('wrapAll()');
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.text-inverse'), wrap);
  reverseOddLinesWithChars();
  console.timeEnd('wrapAll()'); 
}
wrapAll();
window.onresize = wrapAll;



function reverseOddLinesWithChars() {
  var textInverseHolder = document.getElementsByClassName("text-inverse")[0].children;
  
  for (var i = 0, length = textInverseHolder.length; i < length; i++) {
    var isOddLine = i%2;
    if (isOddLine) {
      var currentLine = textInverseHolder[i];
      var words = currentLine.innerHTML.split(" ");
      var reversedWords = reverseCharOrderOfWords(words);
      
      currentLine.innerHTML = reversedWords.join(" ");
    }
  }
}

function reverseCharOrderOfWords(words) {
  words.forEach(function (word, index, array) {
        var newWord = word.split("").reverse().join("");
        newWord = placeDotOrCommaOnOtherSide(newWord);
        words[index] = newWord;
  });

  return words;
}

function placeDotOrCommaOnOtherSide(word) {
  if (word.charAt(0) === ".") {
    return returnCharOnOtherSide(word, ".");
  } else if (word.charAt(0) === ",") {
    return returnCharOnOtherSide(word, ",");
  }
  
  return word;
}

function returnCharOnOtherSide(word, char) {
  return word.split(char)[1] + char;
}
```

```css
.text-inverse div:nth-child(2n) {
  direction: rtl;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="courses">
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <time class="date" datetime="2016-11-08"></time>
  <p class="course text-inverse">One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided by arches into stiff sections. The bedding was hardly able to cover it and seemed ready to slide off any moment.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: you almost got it, but i need this for letters, not for words

Comment: I see you changed your answer. Thanks for your tips, but it still for words and not for letters... Maybe more ideas?

Comment: Oh sorry, I did re-edit the answer, because I thought this solution would be easier. I replace the previous one with the letters.

Comment: Please give me an example how you want the sentences end up!
Because we did now both, words and letters. The CSS reverses the words and letters. And I re-reversed the letters now

Comment: Unfortuanelly, I don`t have examples. You made great job, but you, with letters, re-reversed words.

Just for simple example, word "his" must be "sih", but with re-reversed or just reversed letters